# Is BigInteger.longValue() guaranteed to preseve the unsigned binary for 2^63 <= x <= 2^64-1?

Tags: java, java-7, biginteger, signed

What I want to do is storing a 64-bit unsigned integer as a `Long` type, *preserving its interval binary representation*.

For example, I want to save

2^63-1 = 9223372036854775807 as it is (9223372036854775807) (∵ 2^63-1 <= Long.MAX_VALUE)

and

2^63 = 9223372036854775808 = 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000<sub>(2)</sub> as **-9223372036854775808**
because 10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000<sub>(2)</sub> is -9223372036854775808's binary representation for the signed 64-bit integer type.

Likewise, I want to save 2^64-1 = 18446744073709551615 as **-1**
because (unsigned) 18446744073709551615 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF and (signed long) -1 = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF

JavaDoc for `BigInteger.longValue()` says that

> Converts this BigInteger to a long. This conversion is analogous to a
>   narrowing primitive conversion from long to int as defined in section
>   5.1.3 of The Java™ Language Specification: if this BigInteger is too big to fit in a long, only the low-order 64 bits are returned. Note
>   that this conversion can lose information about the overall magnitude
>   of the BigInteger value as well as return a result with the opposite
>   sign.

However, I am not sure it is guaranteed to work as I intended.

Will `BigInteger(string).longValue()` be enough for my purpose where `string` is the string representation of the original integer?

---

*Update*: I am using JDK 1.7, so `Long.parseUnsignedLong()` is not available.

Comment: You can use a Java 7 compatible library that provides that operation.  Guava has Java 7 compatible versions of `UnsignedLongs.parseUnsignedLong`.

Comment: OK. Guava works for this. Thanks.

Comment: I think you forgot a few zeroes in the binary representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, I would just run the code and see what happens.

```
println(new BigInteger("2").pow(63).longValue());
println(new BigInteger("2").pow(63).subtract(new BigInteger("1")).longValue());
println(new BigInteger("2").pow(64).longValue());
println(new BigInteger("2").pow(64).subtract(new BigInteger("1")).longValue());
```

Outputs

```
-9223372036854775808
9223372036854775807
0
-1
```

So yes, BigInteger.longValue() does exactly what you think it does (and according to the reading of the docs, this is the guaranteed behavior. AKA, it is converted to a bit array, and only the low 64 bits are kept and used as long value, ignoring the fact that the 64'th bit is actually the sign bit).

Answer (score 1):

You should use unsigned long methods in `Long` class.

```
String s = "18446744073709551615"; // 2^64 - 1
long value = Long.parseUnsignedLong(s);
System.out.println("long value = " + value);
System.out.println("unsigned long value = " + Long.toUnsignedString(value));
```

result

```
long value = -1
unsigned long value = 18446744073709551615
```

Comment: I am using Java 7 now.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know that.